# Connecting to JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, derby

When trying to connect to a local database using JDBC and Apache Derby with a Properties file, I get the following exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Database 'Mobsters' not found.
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.newSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleDBNotFound(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver$1.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.getNewEmbedConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
at com.adrian.mobsters.gui.controllers.MainController.getDBConnection(MainController.java:401)
at com.adrian.mobsters.gui.controllers.MainController$2.call(MainController.java:388)
at com.adrian.mobsters.gui.controllers.MainController$2.call(MainController.java:376)
at javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable.call(Task.java:1423)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: ERROR XJ004: Database 'Mobsters' not found.
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
    ... 22 more
```

I am using a properties file:

```
create=true
databaseName=Mobsters
user=myuser
password=mypw!
shutdown=true
```

I know the database doesn't exist. Shouldn't this create the database? This is am embedded application database that should be created if it does not exist.

Code used to setup database connection:

```
public void initializeDB() {
    Task<Void> task = new Task() {
        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
            Properties properties = loadDBProperties();
            // Decide on the db system directory: <userhome>/.addressbook/
            String userHomeDir = System.getProperty("user.home", ".");
            String systemDir = userHomeDir + "/.mobsters";
            new File(systemDir).mkdir();
            // Set the db system directory.
            System.setProperty("derby.system.home", systemDir);

            getDBConnection(properties);

            MobsterDBUtils.createMobsterTable(getDBConnection());
            return null;
        }
    };

    new Thread(task).start();
}

public void getDBConnection(Properties properties) {
    String url = "jdbc:derby:";
    try {
         connection.set(DriverManager.getConnection(url, properties));
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

public Properties loadDBProperties() {
    Properties prop = new Properties();

    InputStream is = MainController.class.getResourceAsStream("/derby/DerbyConfig.properties");

    try {
        prop.load(is);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return prop;
}
```

As far as I know, the properties file is being properly imported:

[image]

(this isn't confidential login information)

Comment: FYI. None of the answers are answers, They should be deleted. Mobsters != mobsters. Try using same case. If "mobsters" maps to some storage location, it could subject to case sensitivityIf this works I will post it as an answer

Comment: @efekctive the issue was shutdown=true should only be added when closing the connection. However, that may be the answer to my other issue: the database doesn't save but does initialize.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `shutdown=true` to the URL will shut the connection down. With this property added, the database is not created. This should be used when done with the database connection.

Comment: @abhijit-sarkar So, yes author is right, when this property will be found, debry will try to shutdown db instead of creating new one. Refer about it is below
https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.13/ref/rrefattrib16471.html

Comment: @Batiaev The URL you linked to has nothing about creating a DB, it only explains what the `shutdown` parameter does.

Comment: Yes it is, I mean if you will try to create connection with that param - you will shutdown requested database instead of creating as you probably expect
One more link about that - 
https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.9/devguide/tdevdvlp40464.html